# Hello contract: How do i execute "hi" action when notified by eosio.token contract of an EOS transfer?

Tags: smart-contract, blockchains, transfer, eosio.token

I want to extend the Hello contract (as an exercise)

How do i execute "hi" action when notified by eosio.token contract of an EOS transfer ?

I understood i have to extend EOSIO_ABI macro to handle eosio.token transfer notification, but i cannot get it working.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post to include the code you have written, then we will find your error easily.

Comment: Did you provide the permission of eosio.code to your contract? you are using eosio.hpp as a header file so first you have to provide the permission of eosio.code to your contract, as Philip said it would be better if you share code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way by redefining EOSIO_ABI.

The "transfer" function in my contract get called when an EOS transfer is done through eosio.token contract.

```
#undef EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
extern "C" { \
  void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) { \
     if( action == N(onerror)) { \
     /* onerror is only valid if it is for the "eosio" code account and authorized by "eosio"'s "active permission */ \
     eosio_assert(code == N(eosio), "onerror action's are only valid from the \"eosio\" system account"); \
  } \
  auto self = receiver; \
  if( code == self || code == N(eosio.token) || action == N(onerror) ) { \
     TYPE thiscontract( self ); \
     switch( action ) { \
        EOSIO_API( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
     } \
     /* does not allow destructor of thiscontract to run: eosio_exit(0); */ \
     } \
  } \
}

 EOSIO_ABI(ping_contract, (ping) (transfer) )
```

I used something like this for the permission:

```
cleos set account permission CONTRACT_ACCOUNT active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key":"CONTRACT_ACCOUNT_PUBKEY","weight":1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"CONTRACT_ACCOUNT","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p CONTRACT_ACCOUNT@active
```

Comment: Actually you don' need to redefine EOSIO_ABI if you provided the permission , all you have to do is to make a new .cpp file and define a action that you want and use the transfer action of eosio.token. Also you have to import `<eosiolib/eosio.hpp>`